# Client IP address in UserNamePasswordValidator

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF REST rest service, that is hosted by a Windows Service. It uses custom UserNamePasswordValidator authentication.

I'd like to get client ip address when authenticating:

```
ublic static string GetClientIPAddress()
    {
        try
        {
            var context = OperationContext.Current;
            var prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
            var endpoint = prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
            return endpoint.Address;
        }
        catch (System.Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false,exc.Message);
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

But it throws an exception, because context is null in that case. How can I solve this? Note, the mostly suggested asp.net compatibility mode is not an option, my service is hosted by a WIndows Service, NOT by IIS.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not using IIS ?

Comment: Because I have to install it to more machines, where IIS is not used

Comment: but if you are making a .net application you gone put the app. on a server and install there IIS and thats it so you dont need to install it on every client ..

Comment: Thanks, but it is not a question, it is a fact, it must be ran without IIS

Comment: The ASP.NET compatibility answer is everywhere, unfortunately, which makes searching for a solution to your problem very challenging.  I've been trying to knock down this wall for the past few hours.  I tried using a custom IErrorHandler, but unfortunately the custom UserNamePasswordValidator's Validate method seems to be the last thing called on a validation failure.  Any exceptions thrown from there, whether FaultException or otherwise, don't end up handled by IErrorHandler.  The UserNamePasswordValidator runs on its own thread, so the context of the call is null in calls to Validate.

Answer (score -1):

Heey try that solution that should work .

```
private string GetClientIp(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpContext"))
    {
        return ((HttpContextWrapper)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
    }
    else if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name))
    {
        RemoteEndpointMessageProperty prop;
        prop = (RemoteEndpointMessageProperty)this.Request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name];
        return prop.Address;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would `HttpRequestMessage` come from if no context is available?

Comment: Posting an answer with a private method with no context of where it's called isn't helpful.